# How to debug groovy code in eclipse (Play-Framework)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, groovy, playframework

I play a little with "Play" (I love this sentence) and tried to set up a breakpoint within the html file. Of course the eclipse editor has no such option, only bookmark text is available.

I also tried the eclipse plugin from [codehouse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) but unfortunately it only supports groovy code in a java file.

Is there a possebility to set a breakpoint in html files and debug groovy code?
I'll be really thankful for any hint.

Short overview about my system:

- eclipse 3.6
- play 1.2.3

Comment: put he groovy code in a groovy file and you can put  break points there.It should not be in HTML any way.

Comment: The problem is that play works with html-files to present the web pages and there is groovy code inside.
In my case there is no possibility to rename the file. It is also mixed with html content...

Comment: Workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758688/debugging-groovy-scripts-running-in-a-scriptengine-from-eclipse/23511693#23511693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that it's not possible to set a breakpoint in groovy template. The best way to debug is to refresh the page and check. It's troublesome but that's the only way. I believe that's one of the reasons the author is moving to Scala template in Play 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, that could be one reason of course, another one would be the performance I guess. Anyway I have to admit that there is no solution even STS with display view and expressions view are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that is not possible. You can debug whole the Java part but not the Groovy part that is compiled...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set a breakpoint in an html file and expect it to be reached by the debugger.  However, it is possible to set breakpoints in Groovy files.

Furthermore, if you install STS, then you can get the display view and expressions view working for Groovy stack frames.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have no idea what STS means and quicksearch via google wasn't successfull.

Comment: @Tobias STS means Spring Tools Suite: http://www.springsource.com/products/springsource-tool-suite-download

Comment: Thanks, @romaintaz, forgot to add a link.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it's not the right place to write it, but is there an example for the STS and Groovy part you mentioned @AndrewEisenberg? I have no idea how it looks like or how it works. A short impression would be great, or in fact a small guide how I can use it for my needs.

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/30/new-groovy-debug-support-in-sts-2-5-1/

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you. If STS is useable for my problem then I'll accept your answer :D

Comment: I tried STS with display view and expressions view but unfortunately it doesn't help me. Thank you for your hint.