# Debugging groovy scripts

Tags: java, debugging, groovy

I have bunch of **Groovy** scripts and I execute them from **Java** *(so I haven't .class files for this scripts, I compile them on the fly)*.

- Can I somehow debug this scripts from Netbeans?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758688/debugging-groovy-scripts-running-in-a-scriptengine-from-eclipse/23511693#23511693

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this since there is no way to tell Netbeans to attach the debugger to the script from your Java code.

But this answer contains a workaround so you can set breakpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23511693/34088